# Accessing location variable outside of locationmanager func?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
class EditProfileViewController: UITableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

var manager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager.delegate = self 
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    if iOS8 {
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    aboutText.delegate = self
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    if locations.count > 0 {
        self.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        let location = locations[0] as! CLLocation
        var currentLocation = PFGeoPoint(location: location)
    }
}

@IBAction func singlecomparepost(sender: AnyObject) {
var post = PFObject(className: "Post")

post["location"] = currentLocation
post.saveInBackground()

}
```

Thats how my code is but I can't access `currentLocation` at the `singlecomparepost` function. Is there a way to set the location as a variable for the whole view controller?

Comment: create currentLocation variable right below manager variable. And it will be in the scope of your class. And your function will have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the variable in your view controller like:

```
private var currentLocation: PFGeoPoint? // Here private modifier defines access control and restricts the use of the currentLocation to this source file
```

Set it in `locationManager: didUpdateLocations:` callback and use it in `singlecomparepost`:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    if locations.count > 0 {
        self.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        let location = locations[0] as! CLLocation
        currentLocation = PFGeoPoint(location: location)
    }
}

@IBAction func singlecomparepost(sender: AnyObject) {
   if let location = currentLocation {
      post["location"] = location
      post.saveInBackground()
   }
}
```

Comment: Explain the `private` part if you mention it. (or provide a link)

Comment: currentLocation = PFGeoPoint(location: location)
im getting cannot assign type PFGeopoint for a value type CLLocation? for that

Comment: I've updated the answer above. The type of currentLocation should be `PFGeoPoint?`. Means, use `private var currentLocation: PFGeoPoint?`.

Comment: no errors but it isn't posting the geolocation, when i println(location) i get back <PFGeoPoint: 0x17042b340>

Comment: If you'd like to post your location when you get `locationManager: didUpdateLocations :` callback, call `singlecomparepost(self)` after `currentLocation = PFGeoPoint(location: location)`

Comment: cant seem to get it to work. only way it seems to work is if i save it to PFUser in the locationManager function and then call it back from Parse in the singlecomparepost func post["location"] = PFUser.currentUser()["location"], can u give me an example of that and pretend like ive been coding for 5 days?

Comment: OH, it was working..... Parse just updates new objects on the website really slowly.

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, the same way you have defined you CLLocationManager, but remember func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) is asynchronous so you need to wait until the Location Manager has been updated the device location.

Comment: `var currentLocation: PFGeoPoint?
    
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        if locations.count > 0 {
            self.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            let location = locations[0] as! CLLocation
            currentLocation = PFGeoPoint(location: location)
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func singlecomparepost(sender: AnyObject) {
        var post = PFObject(className: "Post")
        
        post["location"] = currentLocation
        post.saveInBackground()
        
    } `